# how to update a UILabel's Text from AppDelegate.m file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I'm new in Objective-C Programming. I want to get the text from a UILabel and at least NSLog that when the application enters the background. but all i got was a null value.(I don't know why!). I'm using story boards to create the view and UILabel and i have used CTRL+Drag to hook the label to my code and synthesized that in the implementation file. but I just get a null value in AppDelegate.m codes.

These are my codes:

ViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Mylabel;
```

ViewController.m:

```
@synthesize Mylabel;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[viewController Mylabel] text]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewController * viewController = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NSLog(@"This is my text: %@", viewController.Mylabel.text);
```

As you're new to Objective-C, I will point out that you should not ever every capitalize your property values (AKA Mylabel). Always use camel case for properties and methods. Methods use [ ] to call, properties you use . notation to access and set. You also don't need to synthesize Mylabel as this is done automatically for you. I recommend looking at the iOS by Apprentice book provided by [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com) to get up to speed.

Comment: ... ok, normally I wouldn't care... but why did someone actually down vote me for this. If someone doesn't agree with anything I said above or my answer, I would love a good explanation. Especially since everything I said above is correct while the methodologies I mention are defined by Apple themselves. If you down vote me for this, explain why (and don't mis lead people new to Objective-C)

Comment: No problem, good luck on the journey we know and love as Objective C (and upcoming Swift).

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of ViewController in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method of `AppDelegate.m`, rather than accessing the existing instance.  As a quick fix, you should find `self.window.rootViewController` points to your existing instance.  So change your code to:

```
NSLog(@"Label text is %@",self.window.rootViewController.Mylabel.text);
```

Note the use of 'dot' notation to access properties (it's easier).  And FYI, tradition has it that properties begin with a lowercase letter; you might want to change Mylabel to myLabel, to get into the habit!

Comment: thanks that's what i was looking for. thank you. but TheGamingArt had a better answer